# SQL Server 2005 The multi-part identifier "x" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, syntax

I think I'm having a syntax problem, but I'm struggling to find an answer...

Could anyone explain why

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Facilities 
        INNER JOIN FacilityStates 
        ON FacilityStates.Asset = Facilities.ID
        WHERE Facilities.ID = 'MyFacility'
```

compiles and returns a suitable result, but what I think is the fully qualified version

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [dbo].[Facilities] 
               INNER JOIN [dbo].[FacilityStates]
               ON [dbo].[FacilityStates.Asset] = [dbo].[Facilities.ID]
               WHERE [dbo].[Facilities.ID] = 'MyFacility'
```

throws "The multi-part identifier "x" could not be bound." for the left and right parts of the 'on' clause and the 'where' clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are combining your `Table.Column` in one set of square brackets:

```
....
ON [dbo].[FacilityStates.Asset] = [dbo].[Facilities.ID] 
....
```

This should be:

```
....
ON [dbo].[FacilityStates].[Asset] = [dbo].[Facilities].[ID] 
....
```

Square brackets in SQL Server are used to explicitly denote an object name that could contain spaces or be a reserved word.  So when you combined `FacilityStates.Asset` within one set of brackets, you were telling SQL Server that there is an object with that name.  Which there is not.

Answer (score 1):

It's your placement of square brackets:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [dbo].[Facilities]  
               INNER JOIN [dbo].[FacilityStates] 
               ON [dbo].[FacilityStates].[Asset] = [dbo].[Facilities].[ID] 
               WHERE [dbo].[Facilities].[ID] = 'MyFacility'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to figure out that everything inside square brackets is one name. You framed with sq. brackets table and field names together. The valid query is:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * 
FROM [dbo].[Facilities] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[FacilityStates]
  ON [dbo].[FacilityStates].[Asset] = [dbo].[Facilities].[ID]
WHERE [dbo].[Facilities].[ID] = 'MyFacility'
```